# Getting a directory size

Tags: file, vba

I need to find the size of a folder and display the size in KB in a textbox.

Can anyone help me do this and give me an example as currently i have tried to use the method below but it only lets you find the size of files and not folders and it only displays it in bytes, not Kilobytes.

```
    Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo
    infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\imdb\bgs")
    MsgBox("File is " & infoReader.Length & " bytes.")
```

Comment: Is that VBA? looks like VB.NET

Comment: Also KB = bytes * 1024

Comment: You're using the `System.IO` dll in VBA code? How are you referencing it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on how you are using the `System.IO` assembly but if you use the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll) you can get a `Folder` and `File` objects which have a size property expressed as bytes.

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim sizeInBytes  As Long
sizeInBytes = fso.GetFolder("C:\imdb\bgs").Size
Debug.Print sizeInBytes
sizeInBytes = fso.GetFile("C:\imdb\bgs\.somefile.txt").Size
Debug.Print sizeInBytes
```